# Comparing two strings in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```
function nameIsDuplicate(name){
    objects = $("#content").find('p.itemOldName');
    $(objects).each(function(i, object){
        console.log("*"+($(object).text()).toLowerCase() + "*" + name.toLowerCase()+"*");
        if(($(object).text()).toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase())
            return true;
    });
    return false;
}
```

I am building an online file manager system.
the `name` argument is a name provided by the user via a textbox, and the `$(object).text()` is the name of files and folders in the current directory. These names come via `exec("ls")` command.

I need to check if the name provided by the user already exists. So I compare the `name` with every files/folders name. The problem is it doesn't find duplicates. The result of the above code is given in the following image

[image]

Comment: one advise is that don't use exec. It make your system a playground for clients

Comment: Why the `()` around `$(object).text()`, you sure that is needed?

Comment: When you are reading text from DOM, there is a possibility of extra white spaces. Use `.trim()` to clear them. Also to check instead of logging value, log their lengths

Comment: You are returning from callback not from the function.

Comment: @SagarV The system is in a local network, not on the internet. I also will limit access to certain directories.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Nicely spotted.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Because I need to get the string, then convert it to lower case.

Comment: Did you try to use `$(this)` instead of `$(object)`?

Comment: I think you are not getting the values for $(object).text(), try to keep a breakpoint inside the each and check if you are able to the access the text. You can use firebug to debug or try developer tools.

Comment: Just replace the each loop with a classic for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return true` returns out of the `each` callback. That has no effect on `each` (it only cares about `return false`) and doesn't do anything to set the return value of `nameIsDuplicate`.

You want to `return false` there (no need to keep looking) and set a flag so your `nameIsDuplicate` can return it:

```
function nameIsDuplicate(name){
    var duplicate = false;
    objects = $("#content").find('p.itemOldName');
    $(objects).each(function(i, object){
        console.log("*"+($(object).text()).toLowerCase() + "*" + name.toLowerCase()+"*");
        if(($(object).text()).toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
            duplicate = true;
            return false; // Stop looping
        }
    });
    return duplicate;
}
```

**However**, that function can be a lot simpler using `Array.prototype.some`:

```
function nameIsDuplicate(name){
    var objects = $("#content").find('p.itemOldName');
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    return objects.get().some(function(object) {
        return $(object).text().toLowerCase() === name;
    });
}
```

`some` calls its callback for each entry in the array. If the callback returns a falsy value, `some` keeps going; if the callback returns a truthy value, `some` stops. `some`'s return value is `true` if a call to the callback returned a truthy value, `false` if not.

Comment: true, can be one line solution

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return `true`, because you are in `each` loop... should be something like this:

```
function nameIsDuplicate(name){
    var same=0;
    objects = $("#content").find('p.itemOldName');
    $(objects).each(function(i, object){
        console.log("*"+($(object).text()).toLowerCase() + "*" + name.toLowerCase()+"*");
        if(($(object).text()).toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()){
            same=1; 
            return false;        
        }
    });
    if(same){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Other solution:

```
function nameIsDuplicate(name){
    return $("#content").find('p.itemOldName').filter(function(){return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();}).length;
}
```

Comment: Also, just return `same` or `!!same`. No need for `if..else`